# C++ Program to update Bind9 DNS

Tags: c++, dns, debian, bind, named

Just updated my post to clarify that i use Bind9/named DNS. I found libraries but most implement their own DNS so i can't use them.
I want to do a c++ program (running on linux/debian) to update a local DNS using bind9 with new records and then propagate informations so other nodes can update their local DNS. 
Actually I got a solution but i would like to know if there was a more proper way to do it (with some libs for example), and after that create new types of records and not only NAPTR.

I have messages with various informations (service/domain) and I am already using theses informations to create NAPTR records, but the method is very ugly. I write into a txt file all the nsupdate command i need for example :

```
std::ofstream nsupdateCommand("/tmp/nsupdate.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
nsupdateCommand << "update add" << enumName << "." << zone << ". "<< ttl << " NAPTR ";
[...]
nsupdateCommand << "send";
nsupdateCommand.close();
system("nsupdate -l -v /tmp/nsupdate.txt")
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to update the DNS in c++, maybe using sockets or a library?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at DNS library in your language of choice: a good one should give you the same feature as nsupdate which just create a proper DNS packet to send to an authoritative nameserver, so libraries can do the same.

Comment: I found some but i don't know which one to use, because i am not familiar with libraries at all. And most are using C and not C++.

Answer (score 1):

```
ldd `which nsupdate` |grep dns
        libdns.so.81 => /usr/lib64/libdns.so.81 (0x000000348b000000)
rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libdns.so.81
bind-libs-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5.x86_64
```

On CentOS you need to install `bind-devel` to get the header files for `bind-libs`.  Other distros may package them under slightly different names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i can't find the link between it and my question

Comment: Many command line programs just give user interaction to a library which implements the logic.  nsupdate is one example, but the method I showed is useful for finding the programmatic interface for many similar cases.